How do I extract the color of an excel shape using the xml?
I have the below code which works beautifully to extract the text from all shapes in an excel file. For a simple xlsx with 2 sheets and 1 shape per sheet it will return the following:
['Text box 2']
['Sheet2 ellipse text 3']
However, I am needing it to also return the color of the shape. I cannot use xlwings or pywin32 as those take too long to process. I do not believe that openpyxl has this feature.
from zipfile import ZipFile
from lxml import etree

def main():
    z = ZipFile('/home/luis/tmp/shapes.xlsx')
    drawings = [ drw for drw in z.filelist if "drawings" in drw.filename.split('/') ]
    for drw in drawings:
        with z.open(drw.filename) as sstr:
            ssdata = sstr.read()
            
            tree = etree.fromstring(ssdata)
            ns = {"xdr": "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing",
                  "a": "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main", 
                  "r": "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
                  }
            shapes = tree.xpath('//xdr:txBody[preceding-sibling::xdr:spPr]/a:p/a:r/a:t/text()', namespaces = ns)
            
            print(shapes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Get shape geometry, body color and line color as
shape_att = tree.xpath('//xdr:spPr/a:prstGeom/@prst | //xdr:spPr/a:solidFill/a:srgbClr/@val | //xdr:spPr/a:ln/a:solidFill/a:srgbClr/@val', namespaces=ns)

result
['ellipse', '729fcf', '3465a4']

Xpath expressions for any shape/attribute can be found manually extracting
xl/drawings/drawing1.xml
from the xlsx file.
After that xpath expressions are similar to any other XML.
Opening the xml with a browser and using dev console to copy some xpath it could give
/xdr:wsDr/xdr:twoCellAnchor[2]/xdr:sp/xdr:spPr/a:solidFill/a:srgbClr

Shortened in the above expression to and appended with attribute expression @val
//xdr:spPr/a:solidFill/a:srgbClr/@val

